How noisy are EcoFlow battery backup and power station products in HF?
I'm thinking about replacing some near-EOL UPSs with EcoFlow products (for one thing, they use LiFePo4 instead of lead/acid and so are smaller and lighter) but before doing so I was wondering if anyone had heard anything about how noisy they are in the HF band.

Don't rely on hearsay; you'll get people with wildly different expertise and wildly different problems (many of which will not even be related to EMI) giving you "insights". Instead, rely on measurement reports. These things probably have been measured for EMI.
Since I assume these copuld be bought legally in the US at some point in the last decades, they will have an FCC id if they were certified, or you get a letter of "Self-Declaration of Conformity" from the company. With an FCC ID, you can look up their documents in the official database, here.
ECOFlow's FCC Grantee ID is 2A2P9, and as of today, if you just search for that, you get 58 results. Which is quite possible to click through until you find your device, but any even remotely trust-worthy sell would also just tell you the FCC ID of the device they're selling you if you ask them (and quickly so without trying to evade the question). Most of them seem to be intentional emitters (so, things that are meant to transmit radio waves). Which suggests that the company self-declares conformity.
Which means that they have done the testing in-house, then took screenshots, and wrote a letter where they say, "we, the importers of EcoFlow Inc products into the US, certify that we have done the testing and these products are fine". So, write them an email and ask for their SDoC, and tell them you need to use their power thing for sensitive radio equipment, and you would like to know the power spectral density of emitted and conducted emissions in between 3 and 30 MHz.
Simple as that. Personal anecdotes about consumer electronics are honestly quite worthless in an economy where any supplier might (and has to, when parts become more expensive all the time!) change the internals of a device, without changing what it looks like from the outside. Guarantees about "we're not causing more noise than this and that" is where it's at. You buy it, it causes more noise, you send it back and say "full refund or I need to talk to the FCC about your false self-certification". That's what these regulations are for: to protect systems from noise :)
PS: you might want to do that sending back before the next US administration makes true on their announcements to gut consumer protection and industrial regulation boards.

Another approach is not to trust anything and buy an equipment for which schematic and pcb diagrams are available. The noise is generated in switching devices like MOSFETs and IGBTs. A small component called snubber (a RC series circuit in one package) should be used to limit the rate of change in voltage and current around the switching devices, which in turns limits the amount of harmonics generated. Those components cost a few pennies each. Those are usually implemented in the initial production lot but often quietly omitted subsequently. We have all this noise for someone sparing pennies.

I guess I trust the schematics (most of the time) and the right to repair/modify/improve. As they say, "in schematics we trust."
